# Geometry and physics

Tags: geometry, epistemology

I'm searching for references, articles and books, that discussed the geometrization of modern (and contemporary) physics, in a philosofical point of view. Something in the way that Michael Friedman did in "Space-time foundations theories" or Tian Yu Cao did in "The conceptual foundations and philosophical aspects of renormalization theory" or yet, what Roberto Torreti did in "Relativity and Geometry".

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to know? In other words, how would you pose your question without asking for references?

Comment: This is exactly what I want: references. I'm trying to write a project for a Ph.D application in philosophy, and the question that my advisor put for me is: how is the influence of geometrical approach on the scientific heuristic ? And if there's a way to compare the influence of analytical and geometrical approachs. With this motivation, I'm trying to problematize this in a more precise and concrete way.

Comment: The second "motivator" question is, of course, for the case that there's the two approachs. In many cases, they are mix, and in other there's just one of them. The main objective is study the geometrization of physics in the XX century.

Comment: You should better ask directly about the role and importance of geometry in modern physics, pointers to references come then in with the answer most probably without explicitely asking for them.

Comment: Yeah, but it should be a specific question, don't just ask "what is the importance of geometry in modern physics?" It sounds like this sort of thing might be better to bring up in [chat].

Comment: And you should try to focus on the physics, instead of philosophy.

Comment: @DavidZ it should work when he makes several specific questions about the role and importance of geometry in different parts of modern physics, such as general relativity, quantum gravities, renormalization (never heard about that one however?), etc... Chat is pointless, there are no experts who could answer such questions in chat, and even if it gets answered there, the information is barely visibly to other people interested in these topics and not easy to retrieve because it quickly gets flooded down by other chit-chat.

Comment: @Dilaton (1) you know there are people in chat who can answer many types of questions, and (2) of course, chat was not designed to make the information easily visible to other people. Though it _is_ archived and publicly accessible, so someone can always find the information through Google or such.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I have in the more than two years never seen somebody ask for higher level topics references in chat and getting successfully an answer. Chat is like a black hole, the information does not get destroyed and it is archieved, but the information is hidden to the community of active contributors on the main page

Comment: Why google? The information should be accesssible to the community of regular active contributors by searches on the site. That is why sich information should not go into chat but into regular questions and answers to be of use for the _contributing community_ .

Comment: ... However, there once was a books chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8936/books)...